# PF redirect rule: how to limit the rule to specific user

Tags: firewall, freebsd, pf

I was trying to setup a PF redirect rule to force all web traffic from a specific user account to go through a web filter on a shared computer.

With iptables, I can use --uid-owner option to limit the applicability of the rule to certain user like below

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner bob --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

However, I can not figure out how to achieve the same goal with PF's rdr rule. I tried something like below but got syntax error when load the rules with pfctl.

```
rdr inet proto tcp from any to any port www user bob -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no such feature in the FreeBSD version of pf.
Maybe the OpenBSD people have something implemented on that level?